# Listview Contacts filtering from toolbar search

Tags: android, listview, search

I am doing one application in that i display all the contacts from device to ListView (Name, Number, Image). I want to search the contacts from the ListView using the toolbar search. I added search for toolbar but i don't know how to filter the contacts from the list. Please any one help me.

I used [this example](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-contacts-content-provider-retrieving-and-listing-contacts-in-listview-example/) for displaying contacts in ListView.

Comment: It will hlp you :http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-listview-using-filter/

Comment: I placed one edit text and i tried but its not worked for me... and i want searching from tool bar search..

Comment: can you share your code what you try!

Comment: https://spaces.hightail.com/space/jirGD/fi-22c108e8-021b-4cdc-bc6c-67f019ade092/MainActivity.java

Comment: @pskink No i am using simple adapter like this      mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),
                R.layout.list_items,
                null,
                new String[] { "name","photo","details"},
                new int[] { R.id.name_txt,R.id.iv_photo,R.id.num_txt}, 0);  so I am unable to filtering.. It shows error like name feils is not there like that

Comment: No i just send parameters name, image and num... and in that filter also i am filtering with name but its not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below code it working fine:

**Create MainActivity.class:**

```
package app.personal.sampleapp;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements   View.OnClickListener, View.OnFocusChangeListener, SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

protected Toolbar toolbar;
private String id, name, phone, image_uri;
private byte[] contactImage = null;
private Bitmap bitmap;
private int queryLength;
private List<ContactItem> contactItems;
private ListView listView;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private ContactAdapter adapter;
private SearchView searchView;
private MenuItem searchMenuItem;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    init();
    new ContactInfo().execute();

}

private void init() {
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contact_list);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
}


private void readContacts() {
    contactItems = new ArrayList<>();
    ContentResolver cr = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
            null, null, null);
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            ContactItem item = new ContactItem();
            id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            name = Character.toUpperCase(name.charAt(0)) + name.substring(1);
            image_uri = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI));
            if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                    phone = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    phone = phone.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                    phone = phone.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
                }
                pCur.close();
            }
            if (image_uri != null) {
                try {
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media
                            .getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
                                    Uri.parse(image_uri));
                    contactImage = getImageBytes(bitmap);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                contactImage = null;
            }
            item.setId(id);
            item.setName(name);
            item.setContactImage(contactImage);
            item.setPhone(phone);
            contactItems.add(item);
        }
    }
}

private byte[] getImageBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
    return outputStream.toByteArray();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    searchView.setQueryHint(getResources().getString(R.string.type_here));
    searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(this);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}

@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if (!hasFocus) {
        searchMenuItem.collapseActionView();
        searchView.setQuery("", false);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    queryLength = newText.length();
    adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
    return false;
}

public class ContactInfo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        readContacts();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        setListAdapter();
    }
}

private void setListAdapter() {
    adapter = new ContactAdapter(getApplicationContext(), contactItems);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

**Create your customAdapter class:**

```
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ContactAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ContactItem> implements Filterable {

private Context context;
private List<ContactItem> contacts, filterList;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ContactFilter filter;

public ContactAdapter(Context context, List<ContactItem> contacts) {
    super(context, R.layout.contact_row, contacts);
    this.contacts = contacts;
    this.context = context;
    filterList = new ArrayList<>();
    this.filterList.addAll(contacts);
}


@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (filter == null)
        filter = new ContactFilter();
    return filter;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view;
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    if (convertView == null) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_row, parent, false);
    } else {
        view = convertView;
    }
    viewHolder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    viewHolder.photo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.photo);
    viewHolder.number = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.phone);
    viewHolder.name.setText(contacts.get(position).getName());
    viewHolder.number.setText(contacts.get(position).getPhone());
    if ((contacts.get(position).getContactImage()) != null) {
        Bitmap contactImage = getContactImage(contacts.get(position).getContactImage());
        viewHolder.photo.setImageBitmap(contactImage);
    }else {
        viewHolder.photo.setImageResource(R.drawable.dummy_icon);
    }
    return view;
}

private Bitmap getContactImage(byte[] photo) {
    int targetW = 50, targetH = 50;
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(photo, 0, photo.length, options);
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    int imageW = options.outWidth;
    int imageH = options.outHeight;
    int scaleFactor = 1;
    if ((targetW > 0) || (targetH > 0)) {
        scaleFactor = Math.min(imageW / targetW, imageH / targetH);
    }
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    options.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(photo, 0, photo.length, options);
}


public class ViewHolder {
    ImageView photo;
    TextView name, number;
}

private class ContactFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        String data = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        if (data.length() > 0) {
            List<ContactItem> filteredList = new ArrayList<>(filterList);
            List<ContactItem> nList = new ArrayList<>();
            int count = filteredList.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                ContactItem item = filteredList.get(i);
                String name = item.getName().toLowerCase();
                String phone = item.getPhone().toLowerCase();
                if (name.startsWith(data) || phone.startsWith(data))
                    nList.add(item);
            }
            results.count = nList.size();
            results.values = nList;
        } else {
            List<ContactItem> list = new ArrayList<>(filterList);
            results.count = list.size();
            results.values = list;
        }
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        contacts = (ArrayList<ContactItem>) results.values;
        clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < contacts.size(); i++) {
            ContactItem item = (ContactItem) contacts.get(i);
            add(item);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

**Create POJO Class**

```
public class ContactItem {
private String id, name, phone;
private byte[] contactImage = null;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public byte[] getContactImage() {
    return contactImage;
}

public void setContactImage(byte[] contactImage) {
    this.contactImage = contactImage;
}
}
```

**Create MainActivity.xml file:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
</FrameLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/contact_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/frame_toolbar"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Create row Item layout file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="#FFF"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/photo"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/phone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**create toolbar.xml in layout folder:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:background="#f57c00"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />
```

**Create menu_search.xml in menu folder:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:icon="@drawable/search"
    android:title="@string/search_view"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always" />
</menu>
```

**add below code in style.xml file:**

```
<style name="NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
</style>
<style name="PopupMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFF</item>
</style>
```

**add below code in AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
 android:theme="@style/NoActionBar"  // add in application theme 

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement the code from Android Developers page: [Retrieve a list of contacts](https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names)

It's much faster and stable.